# Create a file in a directory using python

Tags: python

I am writing a python script in which I read a text file and I want to create a new text file in another directory.
I wrote the following code:

```
def treatFiles(oldFile, newFile):   
    with open(oldFile) as old, open(newFile, 'w') as new:
        count = 0
        for line in old:
            count += 1
            if count%2 == 0:
                pass
            else:
                new.write(line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    import os
    os.makedirs('NewFiles')
    new = '/NewFiles/' + argv[1]
    treatFiles(argv[1], new)
```

I tried running this code with a text file in the same directory than my python script, but got an error like

> `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/NewFiles/testFile'`

Apparently, it is not clear that `NewFiles` is a directory in which it should create the new file... How can I correct this?

Comment: add the newfiles directory to the root folder (or get rid of the / in front of it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is actually that in unix, `/NewFiles/` means a folder in *the root directory* called `NewFiles`, not in the current directory. Remove the leading `/` and it should be fine.